# Why does MSVC fail to compile this CRTP code?

Tags: c++, templates

I wrote some code that compiles well on recent versions of GCC and Clang, but fails on MSVC:

> invalid template argument for template parameter 'TL', expected a class template

Can anyone please explain is this a bug or have I misunderstood something?

Without partial specialization of `types_list` it works fine on MSVC too.

```cpp
#include <cstdint>
#include <type_traits>

namespace detail
{
    template <std::size_t Index, typename ...Ts>
    struct get
    {
        static_assert(Index < sizeof...(Ts), "types_list::get index out of bounds");

    private:
        template <std::size_t CurrentIndex, typename ...Us>
        struct helper
        {
            using type = void;
        };

        template <std::size_t CurrentIndex, typename U, typename ...Us>
        struct helper<CurrentIndex, U, Us...>
        {
            using type = std::conditional_t<CurrentIndex == Index, U, typename helper<CurrentIndex + 1, Us...>::type>;
        };

    public:
        using type = typename helper<0, Ts...>::type;
    };

    template <template <typename...> typename TL, typename ...Ts>
    struct list_impl
    {
        inline static constexpr std::size_t size = sizeof...(Ts);

        template <std::size_t Index>
        using get = typename detail::get<Index, Ts...>::type;
    };
}

template <typename ...Ts>
struct types_list : public detail::list_impl<types_list, Ts...>
{
};

template <typename T, typename ...Ts>
struct types_list<T, Ts...> : public detail::list_impl<types_list, T, Ts...>
{
private:
    using impl = detail::list_impl<types_list, T, Ts...>;

public:
    using front = typename impl:: template get<0>;
    using back = typename impl:: template get<impl::size - 1>;
};

using t = types_list<int, double>::front;
using t2 = types_list<int, double>::back;
using t3 = types_list<int, char, double>::get<1>;

int main()
{
    t x = 10;
    t2 y = 1.4;
    t3 z = 'a';
}
```

EDIT: More detailed example https://pastebin.com/snRC0EPi

Comment: Presumably this is just a bug dealing with the ambiguous nature of the injected-class-name, which can be used as a type or as a template.  Maybe try with the other value of `/permissive`?

Comment: Why does list_impl need TL anyway?

Comment: @n. 'pronouns' m. Yes, this example is not full, just showing an error. Complete realization contains a lot of methods like `push_back`/`push_front`/.. and uses TL. Main idea here that empty list does not have `back` and `front` members, but other logic should be reused. Take a look at more detailed version (with push_back): https://pastebin.com/snRC0EPi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to be bug indeed. To refer to the current instantiation you can usually omit the template paramter of the current type. This is what MSVC seems to do here. It causes an error because the template expects a template template parameter.

But why you want to use a template template parameter? For CRTP you use the "bound template type".

---

## Update

If you need to instantiate the template with new parameters this can be done easily with a helper type:

```
namespace helper{
    template<
        typename VariadicType
    >
    class GetTemplateOfVariadicType{
    };

    template<
        template <typename...> typename Template,
        typename... Ts
    >
    class GetTemplateOfVariadicType<Template<Ts...>>
    {
    public:
        template<typename... T>
        using type = Template<T...>;
    };
}
```

Usage:

```
using OtherTL = typename ::helper::GetTemplateOfVariadicType<TL>::template type<int, bool, char>;
```

See here: [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/GYGM9K)

Comment: I am using the template template parameter to be able to create `types_list <...>` inside `list_impl`, with <typename TL> I cannot do that. I need it in some cases. You can see in the detailed example how it is used: https://pastebin.com/snRC0EPi

Comment: your updated code (with `GetTemplateOfVariadicType`) will most likely work correctly, but I wanted to avoid hacks like this.

anyway, thanks for help

Comment: I'm not sure if you have seen where the error is raised, exactly. It's not the base class,
it is the using clause (impl...). There MSVC uses the bound type.

Comment: Here you can find a version with a template template parameter but with a modified using clause: https://godbolt.org/z/nh1dYY

Comment: Oh, i did'nt know that inside using clause there is bound type and not template.
Then i can go with such solution, without helper: https://godbolt.org/z/asYGYf

Comment: looks nice... With that local alias template MSVC gets not confused...